# What rounding rule does Python use for converting float to integer?

Tags: python, floating-point

**Edit:** After posting this question, it became apparent that my memory of what happened in older languages was faulty and that there is no fundamental difference, as I just verified by running an equivalent Fortran program. In short, my premise was incorrect. I have decided to leave the question up so that others with related questions can see the responses.

**Original post:** In contrast to earlier programming languages I have worked with (Fortran, C, IDL, etc.), it seems Python is a bit smarter about rounding intelligently when converting floats to integers.  For example, in many languages, the equivalent of

```
x = 1./3.
y = 3.*x
print( int(y))
```

produces 0 because of truncation in the calculation of 1./3.  But Python returns 1, which is usually the preferred result.  But how does Python determine when to ignore slight truncation errors and when not to?   I find that there is an apparently threshold of precision:

```
> int(10.999999999999999)
10
> int(10.9999999999999999)
11
```

where the second line has just one more '9'.  Is the threshold precision a fixed, defined feature of the language or is it implementation dependent?

It would be nice to have a better understanding of when one can count on Python doing "the right thing" and when one can't.  As mentioned, in older languages, this was an issue that required constant close attention, because you knew that even the slightest truncation error could give you a different integer result, and even the order of division and/or multiplication sometimes mattered.

Additional context: I commonly use conversion from float to integer when I need to calculate (from floating point data) the index of an array element that needs to be accessed.

Comment: I'm afraid Python isn't doing anything special here. On a typical machine, Python's `float` type uses IEEE 754 binary64 format floating point and arithmetic is simply following the IEEE 754 rules.

Comment: So `int` is simply doing the obvious thing and truncating. In your first example, `y` already has value exactly `1.0` before the `int` call. Note that the result of the multiplication is rounded, too, and in this case is rounded up to `1.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python3.x division with `/` operator **always** returns a `float`. So that is why `1/3` is not truncated to `0`.

For the second part of your question, actually it is not the `int` function that *rounds* the number. You just can't represent a `float` with that precision so it is rounded up to `11` **before** it is given to `int` function:

```
>>> 10.999999999999999
10.999999999999998
>>> 10.9999999999999999
11.0
```

Comment: I don't think the first part of your answer addresses my question.  There is no exact binary representation of 1/3, so in all languages I've worked with to date, it gets truncated internally to something very slightly less than the true 1/3.  Consequently, 3*x is also very slightly less than 1.0.  In older languages, converting y to an integer would simply throw away the fractional part, so the result would be zero.  This doesn't appear to happen with Python, which seems to suggest a more sophisticated approach to converting floats to integers.

Comment: Well, it's the same thing. `0.333333333333333 * 3` is `0.9999999999999989` and when you put 1 more `3`, it can't be represented by float and rounded: `0.3333333333333333 * 3 == 1.0`

Comment: So if you think second part of my answer addresses your question, it should be all clear now because the idea is same.

Comment: In previous languages, there is no rounding, only truncation. Let's assume 3 digits decimal precision for simplicity.  x = 1/3 = 0.333.   3*x = 0.999 which is not equal to 1.000.  In my thirty years of programming experience, the same exact thing happens with binary floating point calculations.  But not in Python.  Apparently Python is deciding that 0.999 is actually 1.000.  This is the essence of my question.

Comment: No, that's not what Python is doing. Python is behaving here in the same way as the vast majority of other mainstream languages that use floating point. There's no magic; no additional behaviour beyond what the hardware provides. Under IEEE 754 semantics, with IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point and the default, standard, round-ties-to-even rounding mode, `(1.0 / 3.0) * 3.0` *is* exactly `1.0`.

Comment: And yes, because one-third is not exactly representable, `1.0 / 3.0` gives a value slightly smaller than one-third (`0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125`, to be precise). *But*: `3.0` times that value is `0.999999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375`, which again isn't exactly representable in binary64 floating-point, so it again needs to be rounded to the nearest representable value, and in this particular case, that nearest representable value happens to be `1.0` again.

Comment: @MarkDickinson The example you gave seems to assume that there's an intermediate conversion back to decimal, otherwise you wouldn't give a value that you say "isn't exactly representable  in binary64 floating-point."  It would be easier for me to understand using a low-precision (e.g, float32) binary representation that shows exactly what happens without any intermediate reference to decimal.

Comment: That said, I accept your statement that Python isn't doing anything beyond what the hardware does, which is language-independent,  and my original question may have been based on a misperception.   I'll wait a bit for additional comments before deleting my question.

Comment: My examples don't assume any intermediate conversion to decimal. I'm merely showing you the exact values in decimal, for convenience. If you prefer, the result of `1.0 / 3.0` is `0x1.5555555555555p-2`. Multiplying that by `3` would mathematically give an exact result of `0x0.fffffffffffffcp+0`. That value isn't exactly representable (it would take 54 bits to represent exactly, but we only have 53 available), so instead we get the rounded value of `1.0`. These are the exact same numbers, but with different representations. Decimal isn't relevant here; sorry if I gave the impression it was.